# Prolog syntax error: expression expected checking for parentheses

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a program in Prolog where I'm given a set of grammar rules and the user inputs a sentence, I must make sure the sentence follows the given rules.
I'm only stuck on one rule:
expr -> ( expr ) also written as expr -> ( id op expr )

Here is my code for this part:

```
expr(X) :- list(X), length(X, Length), =(Length, 5),
=(X, [Left, Id, Op, Expr | Right]),
=(Left, ‘(‘),
id(Id), op(Op), expr([Expr]),
=(Right, ‘)’).
```

I believe the issue is with checking the parentheses since the other parts of this code are used elsewhere with no errors. When using =(Left, '(') or =(Right, ')') I get a syntax error: expression expected why do I get this error and what would be a better way to check for left and right parentheses?

Comment: In addition to what @CapelliC said about single quotes, your list `[Left, Id, Op, Expr | Right]` has `Right` as a tail, which is a list. So if it's a right paren, it will be `[')']` not `)`, whereas you are comparing with an atom `=(Right, ')')`. You need to write your list as either `[Left, Id, Op, Expr, Right]` or `[Left, Id, Op, Expr | [Right]]` if you want `Right` to be the last atom in a 5-element list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use single quotes here `=(Left, ‘(‘),` and here `=(Right, ‘)’)`. I.e. `=(Left, '('),` and `=(Right, ')')`.

That said, your Expr will only match a single token, and this is not what I expect. Consider to match the entire 'right' sequence with

```
X = [Left, Id, Op | Expr],
```

and further split Expr to get the right parenthesi. Anyway, as I advised in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975799/874024), your parsing (also after correction) will fail on `[a,=,'(',b,')',+,c].`